# app.config for executing a .exe multiple times with different settings

Tags: automation, dynamics-crm-2011, app-config

I'm following the tutorial for http://mscrmshop.blogspot.be/2012/03/how-to-use-crmsvcutil-improved-version.html on autogenerating an XrmServiceContext file for Dynamics CRM 2011 development.

I have a solution with 3 projects. Each project has a slightly different namespace, depending on whether it's for Plugins, Workflows or the web portal. They all share the format company.software.productversion.module, and only module is different. I want to generate 1 file for each project and put them in the appropriate folders, but I only want to build this project once every time I change my CRM configuration, after which it builds 3 context files (1 for each namespace) and places it into the correct folders.

Is there a way to configure the config file for this project so this happens automatically?

Comment: So you want to re-gen your early bound objects only if a particular file has changed?

Comment: no, I want to manually generate them, but all 3 at once.

Comment: You want to have saved configuration settings for 3 different endpoints, so you can be able to perform one action, that generates the 3 different files?

Comment: Yes. The endpoint (i.e. the CRM installation) is the same, but I want to use a different target folder and namespace for each of the 3 projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.  Probably the simplest is to have three different folders, each containing their own CrmSvcUtil and their own config file.  Then in your Post Build Command line (or if you want to run it manually create a batch file), enter the paths to your 3 different CrmSvcUtil's:

```
"$(TargetDir)\Project1\CrmSvcUtil.exe" 
"$(TargetDir)\Project2\CrmSvcUtil.exe" 
"$(TargetDir)\Project3\CrmSvcUtil.exe"
```

Each one will run by itself with it's own settings, and can output it's own context file.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I want to use relative references for the output URL so it can work on other computers as well. since all 3 projects are in the same solution, is there a way to make a URL relative to the solution root so I don't need to rewrite this every time I use this on a different computer? All I can find is '~/', but I cannot find whether this refers to the project root or the solution root.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Checkout the build event macros: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx  `$(SolutionPath)` is probably what you're looking for

Comment: I was referring to the output key in the AppSettings in the CrmSvcutil.exe.config file. Turns out I simply had to use ..\ for every folder I needed to step up into.